# Troubleshooting Spark resource issues

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm experiencing issues with my Spark setup. The exception I'm getting is the following one:

> kernel.js:978 ui-logs-160> [Mon May 29 2017 12:44:45 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)] [org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl] Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources

After googling around I figured that either amount of cores or RAM I'm asking from the cluster is too high and I have to change that.

I've got a mini Spark cluster deployed, which looks like that:
[image]

I've created it using docker-compose, config file:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  master:
    image: gettyimages/spark
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master -h master
    hostname: master
    environment:
      MASTER: spark://master:7077
      SPARK_CONF_DIR: /conf
      SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS: localhost
    expose:
      - 7001
      - 7002
      - 7003
      - 7004
      - 7005
      - 7006
      - 7077
      - 6066
    ports:
      - 4040:4040
      - 6066:6066
      - 7077:7077
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./conf/master:/conf
      - ./data/master:/tmp/data

  worker1:
    image: gettyimages/spark
    depends_on:
      - master
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://master:7077
    hostname: worker
    environment:
      SPARK_CONF_DIR: /conf
      SPARK_WORKER_CORES: 2
      SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: 1g
      SPARK_WORKER_PORT: 8881
      SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT: 8081
      SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS: localhost
    links:
      - master
    expose:
      - 7012
      - 7013
      - 7014
      - 7015
      - 7016
      - 8881
      - 8081
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    volumes:
      - ./conf/worker1:/conf
      - ./data/worker1:/tmp/data

  worker2:
    image: gettyimages/spark
    depends_on:
      - master
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://master:7077
    hostname: worker
    environment:
      SPARK_CONF_DIR: /conf
      SPARK_WORKER_CORES: 2
      SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: 1g
      SPARK_WORKER_PORT: 8882
      SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT: 8082
      SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS: localhost
    links:
      - master
    expose:
      - 7012
      - 7013
      - 7014
      - 7015
      - 7016
      - 8882
      - 8082
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    volumes:
      - ./conf/worker2:/conf
      - ./data/worker2:/tmp/data

  worker3:
    image: gettyimages/spark
    depends_on:
      - master
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://master:7077
    hostname: worker
    environment:
      SPARK_CONF_DIR: /conf
      SPARK_WORKER_CORES: 2
      SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: 1g
      SPARK_WORKER_PORT: 8883
      SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT: 8083
      SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS: localhost
    links:
      - master
    expose:
      - 7012
      - 7013
      - 7014
      - 7015
      - 7016
      - 8883
      - 8083
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    volumes:
      - ./conf/worker3:/conf
      - ./data/worker3:/tmp/data

  worker4:
    image: gettyimages/spark
    depends_on:
      - master
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://master:7077
    hostname: worker
    environment:
      SPARK_CONF_DIR: /conf
      SPARK_WORKER_CORES: 2
      SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: 1g
      SPARK_WORKER_PORT: 8884
      SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT: 8084
      SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS: localhost
    links:
      - master
    expose:
      - 7012
      - 7013
      - 7014
      - 7015
      - 7016
      - 8884
      - 8084
    ports:
      - 8084:8084
    volumes:
      - ./conf/worker4:/conf
      - ./data/worker4:/tmp/data

  worker5:
    image: gettyimages/spark
    depends_on:
      - master
    command: bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://master:7077
    hostname: worker
    environment:
      SPARK_CONF_DIR: /conf
      SPARK_WORKER_CORES: 2
      SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY: 1g
      SPARK_WORKER_PORT: 8885
      SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT: 8085
      SPARK_PUBLIC_DNS: localhost
    links:
      - master
    expose:
      - 7012
      - 7013
      - 7014
      - 7015
      - 7016
      - 8885
      - 8085
    ports:
      - 8085:8085
    volumes:
      - ./conf/worker5:/conf
      - ./data/worker5:/tmp/data
```

I try to query data using [Spark Notebook](http://spark-notebook.io/)

My Spark Conf is the following:

```json
{
  "spark.app.name": "Dockerbook",
  "spark.master": "spark://localhost:7077",
  "spark.executor.memory": "512m",
  "spark.cores.max": "5"
}
```

I assigned half resources than the cluster has, however my code still does not run.

Code I run is pretty straightforward:

```scala
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .getOrCreate

import spark.implicits._

val country = spark.read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
  .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://mssql-host;database=database;")
  .option("dbtable", "dbo.Country")
  .option("user", "bestuserever")
  .option("password", "mostsecurepassword")
  .load()
  .select($"CountryID", $"CountryName")
  .cache()
```

However I end up having the same warning. How do I resolve it?

Comment: Just wondering: you require at least 512 MB of usable RAM per executor, notwithstanding any overhead that Spark may allocate for its internals; and the worker nodes report that they have "approximately" 512 MB of RAM available (give of take a few KB). That feels very optimistic, don't you think...?

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I'm fairly new to Spark and its' internal mechanisms. What you said makes a lot of sense, I'll try to reduce amount of resources even more to check whether things start working or not.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Instead of having 5 workers, I've changed the number to two and granted each of them 3G of RAM and 2 cores. My application (notebook) requests for 512MB/1 Core, which should leave enough of resources for internal Spark mechanisms, but I still experience exactly the same issue :/

Comment: Huh - I'm not familiar with the "standalone" mode, only local / YARN; does the Spark driver run on the same machine as the Notebook, or is it supposed to run inside a worker daemon? _(cf. `spark.driver.memory` = 1G by default...)_ Do you see anything in the Notebook logs about driver/executors being launched? _(insert `log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.Main=DEBUG` at the end of `log4j.properties` to get a maximum of details about Spark-Shell init)_

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter No, the spark driver runs on a different host and I just connect to it and submit my application from the notebook. Driver seems to start correctly, here's a screenshot from console: http://prntscr.com/fddhuo Also my app is recognized from by looking at the master web ui.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I figured out what was the issue. I was running my Spark Notebook on my host in a Docker container. In order to distribute tasks and execute them, Spark Master has to "see" all drivers and my driver was not visible, I've now placed them in a single host and things work well.